# Are matlab C library versions backwards compatible?

Tags: matlab, c++, c

I have some C++ code that links to matlab2008b. Are matlab 2012a and 2012b backwards compatible with 2008b?

If it's not trivially compatible, are there some simple steps to make it compatible?

Comment: It would help if you stated whether you already tried and/or whether you any foundation to think that they may not be compatible...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In each version some functions are added, changed and removed.
As such newer versions are never fully backwards compatible.

That being said, not that much has changed from 2008 to 2012, so there is a good chance that you can get your code to work with no or few adjustments.

Answer (score 3):

Depends. If the C code is too old, it might not compile or link anymore because of name changes in the eng or mx library. I ran into this when i tried to compile some code from 1992 that supposedly provided a Matlab interface to Mathematica. The reason: it used a datatype called `Matrix` which has turned out to be `mxArray` in newer versions of Matlab.